# MigraDoc PDF Reports Renders differently on 2 machines

Tags: .net, pdf, migradoc

I am using [MigraDoc](http://migradoc.codeplex.com/) (v1.32.3885) to render some reports for my .NET 4.0 application which is partially VB.NET and C#.  The main UI is VB.NET but that's irrelevant.  The system has a number of different reports.

One user has an issue displaying these reports incorrectly.  All reports seem to work fine for other users.  I don't know why and don't know where else to go for some information.

Typically report tables are misaligned and the company logo is never displayed - Image Not Found is displayed - even though the user with the issues can load the logo normally into a paint editor.

The application is ran by users from a UNC share where all of the DLLs are also copied.  All user PCs are running the same platform - Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 (32-bit) - which is XP - with .NET4 installed.  I've pieced together a screen where I log all files the application users with the following which are stored in a listview and then copied to clipboard for my analysis:

```
Dim assembly = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim loadedAssemblies = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()

For Each an In loadedAssemblies
        Dim a = Reflection.Assembly.Load(an.FullName)
        Dim fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(a.Location)
        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
        Me.FileVersionsListView.Items.Add(lvi)
        lvi.Text = fvi.FileName
        lvi.SubItems.Add(fvi.FileVersion)
Next
```

All logged files and versions are using the same referenced assemblies - same framework, same file versions (from the above).

The users use Adobe Reader to view the generated PDF reports, but even when I use the MigraDoc.Rendering.Forms.DocumentPreview - the same badly rendered report appears as does in Adobe for this one user.

MigraDoc and PDF Sharp don't seem to have any external dependencies - just the .NET Framework, so I am confused about this one.

Comment: You could try to use PDF differencing in something like Adobe Acrobat to see what the differences are between the two PDFs or use iText RUPS to examine the content of each. Perhaps that can yield some clues.

Answer (score 0):

Same assemblies, different results? MigraDoc loads images and fonts. You get an "Image not found" error message on some computers, so maybe it's a problem with user rights (I understand that the image loads with the Paint editor - maybe it's a simple MigraDoc bug and image loads for users with read/write access but not for users with read access? Just a wild guess ...).

With insufficient rights, MigraDoc sometimes uses the metrics of the font it should use, but cannot embed that font. This usually results in wide gaps between words or in overlapping words.
You can check the list of fonts in the Document properties of the PDF file (in Adobe Reader).

Wild guessing only. Would be easier to analyze with a correct and an incorrect PDF file generated with the same data.

Comment: I am very interested in knowing which rights must be given for that bug not to happen.  I'm experiencing it right now and I had to fall back to Arial for the moment : very wide space between characters, and even start and end of words collide.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mathieu Leblanc: MigraDoc probably uses a different font for metrics than it embeds. I do not know which rights are needed. Give it a test-run with an Application Pool that uses the System account - if the PDF looks OK then you will know it is a rights problem. You can use private fonts. Or find out which rights are needed (I'm afraid I cannot help very much).